# ctype_alnum against SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

Prepared statements do not allow parameterised table names. In order to make sure no code can be inserted I wanted to use ctype_alnum to validate all table names (after removing underscores) that come into the database module to shield the application from errors in other parts.

```
function insert($table) {
    if(!ctype_alnum(str_replace("_", "", $table)))
        throw new Exception("Invalid table name");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES value=:value";
    #... prepare and execute
}
```

Are there attacks which this would not suffice against? I was thinking about for example [multibyte character exploits](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/multibyte-character-exploits-php-mysql)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know any attacks that will work in this case but I won't do it the way you did because `$table` can also contain table that might not exist.

You should have whitelist of `$tables` that you accept so I would do it rather this way:

```
function insert($table)
{
    $table = trim($table);

    if (!ctype_alnum(str_replace("_", "", $table))
        || !in_array($table, $this->tables)
    ) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid table name");
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES value=:value";

    echo $sql;
    #... prepare and execute
}
```

It will ensure that your code will be safe and if someone misspell table name you won't even try execute the code. In fact you can in this case remove `ctype_alnum` from condition as you check if value exists in whitelist array.

Comment: A whitelist array of valid table names is a nice idea! **+1**

Comment: i think with whitelist no longer need to use ctype_alnum function

Comment: While I think whitelisting is a good idea, it might generate some overhead because tables that are created must be added to that white list, which must be available everywhere, updated instantly and checked every time.

Comment: @Samuel You can have such whiltelist in simple PHP file where you return array and include this file in class constructor. If you create table, you can simple add new table and save this file. This is the safest way to secure using table name as variable in my opinion

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek That's true but if the tables are dynamically generated this becomes hard! I figured you could either keep a table of allowed tables or just query the database for existing tables, but that introduces additional complexity and delay! I agree though that for most cases a whitelist is safe and easy ;)

Comment: @Samuel Everything depends on the usage but you could use table names from file normally and if table hasn't been found you could then query database to check if this table exists. Of course it depends how often not existing tables are given here. After such query you would refresh file. You could also put in one extra file not existing tables given as argument, and for example if counter is 10, you wouldn't check in database if they exist or check it after x hours/minutes. Of course it adds some complexity but when you think of security, you shouldn't care about it too much in this case.